# Scanning data from a Website

Tags: java, android, web

I was just wondering if it is possible to use a scanner to read data from a website.  Its not necessarily a text webpage but there are pictures, clickable links, etc.  So How can I only scan the text and not anything else.  This is for an app and I would be reading in names which are subject to change.  That's why I would like to read them from the website instead of making my own text file and reading it that way.  Any help would be great.  Thanks

Comment: you will have to make a http get request usin url and get the required data from the server. What do you mean by scanning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document) for it. It is easy to parse HTML pages using this tool.

You can get the HTML doc and can traverse the elements as mentioned here:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Getting started guide is simple to learn:

[Getting started with JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document)

Comment: This seems like the best solution.  I have downloaded and put the jar file into my libs folder.  Although I am having trouble understand how jsoup works.  Do you know of any step by step tutorials or other information?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a technique named Scraping :

[Web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)